# Where is "relocate" in the netbeans 8's team menu?

Tags: netbeans

I want to relocate a subversion repository url in netbeans. Help file says that this is possible by going to the Team menu in the main menu, and that such a menu will have the option "relocate". However I don't see any relocate option. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans 8.0 Relocate path:
Menu->Team->Working Copy->Relocate->New
Enter New Url here